# What is the purpose of (int *) p here?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

C newbie here and today I was reading about pointers and 2D arrays from a book and I came across this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int s[4][2] = {
        { 1234, 56 },
        { 1212, 33 },
        { 1434, 80 },
        { 1312, 78 }
    };

    int(*p)[2];
    int i, j, *pint;
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        p = &s[i];
        pint = (int*)p;
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
            printf("%d ", *(pint + j));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I really want to know what is the purpose of `(int *) p;` here. From what I can understand here that p is the pointer which stores the address of the entire i th row of the 2D array but I am not being able to understand the purpose of `(int *) p;` and storing it in a variable `pint`.

Comment: It looks like a mistake – should be `pint = *p;`

Comment: @Ry- Mistake or intention -- in any case it is (like most code involving pointers to arrays) rather unidiomatic and unnecessarily complicated. `int *pint = s[i];` would be more common: `s[i]` is an array of 2 ints which decays to a pointer to the first element (which is a single int) when used in a context other than the operand of `sizeof` or `&`. Sure, `&s`, `s` and `*s` all have the same numerical value and it is with arguably all implementations known to mankind safe to arbitrarily cast between these types. But that doesn't mean one should, or that it is conformant.

Comment: @Peter: Well, definitely a mistake on some level – it’s undefined behavior. (Unfortunately, the only answer that pointed it out is now deleted…)

Answer (score 2):

`p` is a pointer to an array of 2 integers. Casting that to `int*` makes it a pointer to a single integer, so it points to the first integer in the array. This is stored in the `pint` variable, which is declared `int*`.

This allows you to index the array by adding an offset to `pint`. In the `printf()` call, `*(pint+j)` is equivalent to `pint[j]`, so the inner loop prints each element of the row of `s`.

Comment: It is UB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78241246/is-casting-pointer-to-array-of-type-to-pointer-to-type-defined/78241399#78241399

Answer (score 1):

The pointer here is a bit redundant, but you need to understand that accessing an index in C is the same as addition.

```
int arr[n];

arr[i] = 5;
// Is translated into
*(arr + i) = 5;
```

When you add to a pointer in C, it multiplies the index (`i`) by the size of each element to get the final address you are trying to access. Keep in mind that since `arr` is an array of `int`'s, each element will be 4 bytes.

If the first element of `arr` is located at `0x1000`, then `(arr + 1)` (i.e. `arr[1]`) will be at `0x1004`.

When doing `p = &s[i];`, you are saving the address of the inner array into the pointer `p`:

```c
p = &s[2];

int s[4][2] = {
    { 1234, 56 },
    { 1212, 33 },
    { 1434, 80 },
//  ^ p
    { 1312, 78 }
};
```

Then you cast it into `pint` which is a pointer to an integer, rather than a pointer to an array of 2 integers. The information is still the same, an address in memory, but the C compiler now interprets it diferently.

Then you add `j` to that `pint` pointer, which is the same ass doing `pint[j]`, `p[j]` or `*(p + j)`:

```c
int s[4][2] = {
    { 1234, 56 },
    { 1212, 33 },
    { 1434, 80 },
//          ^ pint[1]
    { 1312, 78 }
};
```

Comment: It does not answer the question. OP did not as how to optimize the code.

Comment: @gulpr Are you this concerned about your downvote? Haha. I answered the question, I explained the purpose of the variable. OP said he didn't make the code, he wants to understand it. And I don't even understand what you mean by "OP did not as how to optimize the code".

Comment: In this case I believe it is not as simple

Comment: @gulpr What is not that simple? What are you even talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The type cast is needed in the assignment *pint* = (*int* *) *p* because *pint* and *p* have different types; *pint* is a pointer to an integer whereas *p* is a pointer to an array of two integers. The assignment makes *pint* point to the first integer of the *i*:th row in the matrix. Note that *p* + *m* will advance the pointer by matrix rows whereas *pint* + *m* will advance the pointer by matrix elements (integers).

We should also observe that the program is an obscure way of printing the elements in a matrix. Here is how you would normally do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0])

int main(void)
{
    int s[][2] = {
        {1234, 56},
        {1212, 33},
        {1434, 80},
        {1312, 78}
    };
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < LEN(s); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < LEN(s[0]); j++) {
            printf("%d ", s[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```