# Is casting "pointer to array of type" to "pointer to type" defined?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer

As in this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int (*p)[5])
{
    int *i = (int *)p;
    printf("%d\n", *i);
}
```

Is it defined? IMO it is not.

Question inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78241187/what-is-the-purpose-of-int-p-here)

---

Please bear in mind that this question is tagged *`language-lawyer`*

Comment: Since it's a language-lawyer question, you may do good to remove any doubts about implicit declarations and such.

Comment: I know there's an [explicit statement](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15) in the standard that a pointer to a struct can be cast to or from a pointer to its first member: "A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa." Not sure about arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in the C 2018 standard defines this, so the behavior is undefined (4 2: “Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this document by the words ‘undefined behavior’ or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior.”).

A cast performs a conversion (6.5.4 5). Conversions are specified in 6.3. Pointer conversions are specified in 6.3.2.3. Paragraph 1 covers pointers to or from `void *`, which is not the case here. Paragraph 2 covers conversions between differently qualified versions of the same type, which is not the case here. Paragraph 3 covers conversions of null pointer constants, which is not the case here. Paragraph 4 covers conversions of null pointers, which is not the case here. Paragraph 5 covers conversions of integers to pointers, which is not the case here. Paragraph 6 covers conversions to integers, which is not the case here. Paragraph 8 covers conversions of pointers to function types, which is not the case here.

That leaves only paragraph 7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

This applies to our case, **but it does not tell us what the value of the result is**. It tells us when we convert the result back to the original type, we will have a value equivalent to the original pointer. But it is conceivable the converted value is in some encoded form that is not suitable for use for dereferencing.

For example, imagine a version of C designed for debugging in which all pointers are instrumented with provenance information. A pointer to `int [2]` might be 16 bytes, four of which contain the address and twelve of which contain information that this originated as a pointer of type `int [2]`. Converting it to `int *` may yield a pointer with exactly the same bytes, and converting it back would yield the same bytes. Since this is a debugging implementation of C, every time a pointer is dereferenced, it checks the pointer provenance as stored in those bytes. When we use `*p`, it sees that the bytes say the pointer originated as a pointer to `int [2]`, and `p` is that type, so it allows the dereference and the program continues.

However, when we use `*i`, it sees the bytes say the pointer originated as a pointer to `int [2]`, but `i` is `int *`, so it prints an error message and stops the program.

This hypothetical program conforms to the C standard:

- The conversion is allowed, as 6.3.2.3 7 specifies.
- Converting the pointer back yields a pointer equal to the original and that we can use as we used the original, as 6.3.2.3 7 specifies.
- Using the pointer as an `int *` is not specified to work, and it does not work, so that conforms to the standard.

Note further that converting a pointer to a pointer to a character type and using it is specified in the standard to access the bytes representing an object, but our hypothetical C implementation can allow this. It simply approves of the use of any pointer-to-object-type to be used for accessing character lvalues even if the provenance says it originated as some other type.

One may believe the **intention** of the standard was to allow converted pointers to be used as pointers to their new type, but **it does not explicitly say that**. And therefore the behavior is technically not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Yes - I was thinking about the same. But as usually - great answer.

Comment: BTW my correct answer to other question have attracted so many DVs :)

Comment: I don't need to "imagine", I worked with such an implementation years ago: The Symbolics C implementation for Lisp Machines. Pointers were implemented as a tuple of a buffer and offset.

Comment: @Barmar so your answer to the original question is completely wrong

Comment: @gulpr It will not work if someone tries to run it on a machine that hasn't existed for at least 20 years. It will work on practically any machine you can find today.

Comment: @Barmar interesting. So the UB which works on one machine is generally OK in your opinions and programmers should not bother. It works on my machine is OK!

Comment: @gulpr *This* question is a language lawyer question. In practice, lots of UB is not punished.

Comment: @gulpr "Practically any" != "one"

Comment: In the other question I was explaining the intent of the code, not analyzing it as a lawyer.